# How to scroll page in flutter with multiple listviewbuilders

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a page which contains multiple sections and each section is generated using ListView.builder(). 
Here the page problem I'm facing is that , the page is not being scrolled unless the touch is not focused on the widget generated with ListView.

```
  Widget _widget1(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.builder(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }
  Widget _widget2(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.builder(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }
  Widget _widget3(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.builder(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }

  body: Container(
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 140.0,
          child: _offersBanner(context)
        ),
        _widget1(context),
        _widget2(context),
        _widget3(context)
      ],
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 5):

try this, 
  please add below code inside ListView.builder

```
 shrinkWrap: true,
 physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want **four scrolling lists** or just **one combined list**?

- If you want the **former** what you've done should work the way you want.
- If you want the **latter (a combined list)** then you should use column instead of listview in your _widget1, _widget2 and _widget3 classes.

I guess you need the latter.

```
  Widget _widget1(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }
  Widget _widget2(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }
  Widget _widget3(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      ....
       .....
    );
  }
  body: Container(
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 140.0,
          child: _offersBanner(context)
        ),
        _widget1(context),
        _widget2(context),
        _widget3(context)
      ],
    )
  )
```

Comment: I was unable to fix my issue with above solutions . I have four widgets with listview.builder().
The page content exceeds the screen height. I'm unable to scroll the page

Comment: Do you want four scrolling lists or just one combined list?

Comment: I want one combined list that can be scrolled

Comment: Use SingleChildScrollView, add a Column as a child, and the lists as the children of the Column widget

Comment: @KURRUHEM Then you can use my second solution. I've updated my answer with some code.